# How to add csrf token in django with js only without ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I basically want to implement a django view that accepts some json data and then also posts a json data which would be displayed.The confirm group view accepts a list of people via json data , forms a group and then returns the group code back to display.

I was getting the Forbidden(403) CSRF token missing or incorrect Error

I am beginner in django and js so please answer accordingly. Thanking you in advance :)

view.py

```
import json


def confirm_group(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
    grp = Group()
    grp.group_code = group_code_generator()
    grp.save()
    for i in range(len(data)):
        Player = Regplayer.objects.filter(pk=data[i]["pk"])
        pl = Enteredplayer()
        pl.regplayer = Player
        pl.group = grp
        pl.save()
    return JsonResponse(grp.group_code, safe=False)
```

script.js

```
function confirm()
{
    var i = 0;
    var rows= document.getElementById("group").children;
    var num= document.getElementById("group").childElementCount;
    if(num==0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
//      alert("Confirm grouping of "+num+" people?");
        for(i=0; i < num; i++)
        {
            send_name=rows[i].children[0].children[0].innerHTML;
            send_gender=rows[i].children[3].children[0].innerHTML;
            send_clgname=rows[i].children[1].children[0].innerHTML;
            send_sport=rows[i].children[2].children[0].innerHTML;
            send_id=rows[i].children[5].innerHTML;
            myObj["data"].push({"name":send_name, "gender":send_gender, "college":send_clgname, "sport": send_sport, "pk": send_id});
            alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));
        }
        csrf_token = document.getElementById('csrf_token').innerHTML;
        myObj["data"].push({"csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token });

        //POST TO BACKEND
                    // Sending and receiving data in JSON format using POST method
        //
            var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "/confirm_group/";
            ourRequest.open("POST", url, true);
            ourRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            // POST 
            var data = JSON.stringify(myObj);
            ourRequest.send(data);
            // Obtain 
            ourRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (ourRequest.readyState === 4 && ourRequest.status === 200)     {
                    var json = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
                    var groupCode = json.groupcode;
                    //json object received
                    new_group(groupCode);
                }
            };
        // if success call new_group() else call error_handle()
//        new_group();  
        //error_handle();
        //empty json object now

    } 
}
```

index.html

```
<span id="csrf_token" style="display: none;">{{ csrf_token }}</span>
    <div class="confirm-modal">
      <div class="form">
        <p id="modal-text"></p>
        <button class="btn1" onclick="confirm()">Confirm</button>
        <button class="btn2" onclick="close_modal()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: so you want to send `csrf` token from cookies to backend, right?

Comment: @VipinKumar sorry not sure what that means , I just want to rectify the 403 Error .... any additional knowledge appreciated.

Comment: please try this code `ourRequest.open("POST", url, true); ourRequest.withCredentials = true;`

Comment: @VipinKumar sorry still 403 Forbidden error

Comment: Your comment "*[other answers] focused on sending csrf token during an ajax request and not simple js*" doesn't make sense. You *are* making an AJAX request, you just aren't using a library like jQuery to do it. The [information in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) still applies to you - you need get the token (from the template or cookie), and set the header `X-CSRFToken` in your request.

Comment: @Alasdair edited the question. Also I am really a beginner and so would really appreciate if you could put an ans to the question with code. I tried sending csrf_token along with my data but still the same error

Comment: You haven't shown how you tried sending the token. I'm afraid I can't write the Javascript for you. If you are a beginner, then I recommend you use jQuery, then you can use the example from the docs that I linked to.